# Node.js + Append to model before rendering a view

Tags: javascript, node.js, vash

I am building a website using Node.js and Express. For my view engine, I'm using [Vash](https://github.com/kirbysayshi/vash).

In my app, I have a layout.vash file I'm using as the main layout for my app. It looks something like this:

**layout.vash**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>@model.title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    @html.block('content')
  </body>
</html>
```

I then have views that look something like this:

**view.vash**

```
@html.extend('layout', function(model){
    @html.block('content', function(model){
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    })
})
```

The view is referenced via Express with a route similar to this:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var viewModel = {
      title: 'Hello'
    };

    res.render('view', viewModel);
});
```

My `viewModel` will be unique to each view. However, there are some properties that are shared across all views. For example, for development purposes, I would like to know if the request is local or not. If I was using ASP.NET, I know I could say:

`@if (Request.IsLocal) {
...
}`

However, I'm not sure how to do something similar with Node and Vash. My instincts tell me that I somehow need to append a property called `isLocal` to my `model`. However, I'm not sure if that's the correct idea, or if that's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the approach you are considering in my personal code.

If the values you want to attach to your model are common across multiple routes, consider using a function to extend your model:

```
function appendRouteData(model) {
    model.routes = {};
    model.routes.controller = "SomeController";
    model.routes.action = "index";
    model.routes.parameters = { foo: "bar" };
    return model;
}

...

viewModel = appendRouteData(viewModel);
```

In response to your comments, there are multiple ways to include such a function in your `users.js`.

Either expose the method as another module and require it, or, if we're going full crazy, inject a function that performs the same, but this requires some refactoring.  I anticipate you doing only some of this insanity...

```
// routes.js
var UserRoutes = require('./users');
function appendRouteData(controllerName) {
    // some crazy javascript here, might want to contemplate how this actually works first.
    return function (viewModel) {
        viewModel.routes.controller = controllerName;
        return viewModel;
    };
}

module.exports = {
    users: UserRoutes(appendRouteData('users'))
};

// users.js
function UserRoutes(appendRouteData) {
    var router = require('express').Router();
    router.get('/users', function (req, res) {
        var viewModel = {};
        viewModel = appendRouterData(viewModel);
        res.render('users/index', viewModel);
    });
    return router;
}
module.exports = UserRoutes;
```

Comment: Also, it's javascript. (almost) everything is possible.

Comment: I'm still getting my head around *how* to do somethings in JavaScript. Let's say I have a file called routes.js. That file has just this: ``` module.exports = {
  users : require('./users')
}; ```  Then, let's say I have a file called users.js which has the routes for my user paths. That file looks like this: ```var router = require('express').Router(); router.get('/users', function (req, res) { var viewModel = {...}; res.render('users/index', viewModel }); ``` How could I a) put `appendRouteData` in routes.js and b) call appendRouteData from users.js? Thank you!

Comment: You would need a way to introduce appendRouteData to users.js.  This might require some refactoring for this work correctly.  Since comment code formatting sucks, I'll place the code in my answer.